# Docker: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9089: Connection refused

Tags: curl, docker

I am trying to connect to my IAM server by using:

> curl -i -X  POST -H "Content-type: application/json"
>   http://localhost:9089/account/list -d '{"jwt": "jwt_token..."}'

and in doing so I get an error as follows:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9089: Connection refused

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

```
 > npm info it worked if it ends with ok npm info using npm@5.3.0 npm
    > info using node@v8.5.0 npm info lifecycle iam@1.0.2~prestart:
    > iam@1.0.2 npm info lifecycle iam@1.0.2~start: iam@1.0.2
    > 
    > > iam@1.0.2 start /usr/src/app
    > > node server.js
    > 
    > HTTP listening on port 9089 HTTPS listening on port 9449
```

---

```
root@Ubuntu1604-001:/home/src/IAM# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
blandry/2           latest              f127789f2de7        4 days ago          544MB
blandry/3           latest              f127789f2de7        4 days ago          544MB
```

---

```
root@Ubuntu1604-001:/home/src/IAM# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
cc28d00d1667        blandry             "npm start"         33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:32768->9089/tcp   objective_mclean
```

---

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.5.0-wheezy
RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV ldap_port 389
ENV http_port 9089

ENV ladp_ip 10.119.226.149
ENV URL  10.119.226.149
ENV authentication eyJhbGciOiJIUz...

COPY package.json package-lock.json /usr/src/app/
COPY . .

EXPOSE 9089
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: `Connection refused` occurs when nothing is listening on that port (in other words, your service is not running on that port, its either some other port, or service failed to start, or the port is not properly mapped). Provide more details, such as docker logs, container config etc,

Comment: Do you mean the service is not running on the client or server side?

Comment: @ComputerGuy123: By definition, services only run on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost: 32768/account/list -d '{"jwt": "jwt_token..."}'
```

Your docker ps shows

```
root@Ubuntu1604-001:/home/src/IAM# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
cc28d00d1667        blandry             "npm start"         33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:32768->9089/tcp   objective_mclean
```

That means you didn't map `9089` to `9089`. To do that make sure you run your container as

```
docker run -p 9089:9089 <image>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this curl inside a docker you don't need the http prefix. 
I had this same issue yesterday, and I succeeded when I tried sending 
`curl name_of_container:port/path/to/the/method`.

Answer (score 0):

You have mapped 32768 host port with 9089 port of docker.

```
root@Ubuntu1604-001:/home/src/IAM# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
cc28d00d1667        blandry             "npm start"         33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:32768->9089/tcp   objective_mclean
```

Use 32768 port instead of 9089 port.

> curl -i -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json"
>   http://localhost:32768/account/list -d '{"jwt": "jwt_token..."}'